# Construct an analytic function with zeros at intersection of zeros of other analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Given two complex analytic functions f and g on some compact domain $D$, I want to construct a new analytic function h on $D$ such that 
$$h(z) = 0 \iff f(z) = 0\ \text{ and }\ g(z) = 0$$
I want to do this without finding the zeros of $f$ and $g$.
If I wanted to find $h$ such that 
$$
h(z) = 0 \iff f(z) = 0 \ \text{ or }\ g(z) = 0,
$$
this can be easily done by letting 
$$
h(z) = f(z)g(z).
$$

In a more specific version, we can assume that zeros of $f$ and $g$ lie on the real line.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are asking for a simple formula for $h$ I doubt if such a thing exists.

Comment: For polynomials it's just the greatest common denominator. For general analytic functions I have no idea.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy such $h$ does exists. If we assume that $f$ and $g$ are not identically zero, then by isolated zeros, we know that there are finitely many zeros. Let $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ be all the values such that $f(z_i)$ and $g(z_i)$ are zero. Let $h(z) = \prod_{i}(z-z_i)$. But yes, I don't see how to easily compute for $h$.

Comment: @JaeyoonKim Surely, $h$ exists with the desired property. But you appear to seek a simple formula for $h$ and I suspect that no such formula exists.

Comment: If the zeros are simple you may try to find $u,v$ analytic such that $w(z)=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}+e^{u(z)} \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}+v(z)$ has no zeros, so $f(z)g(z)w(z)$ is what you want. Asking if $u,v$ always exist is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no formula of the form $$h(z)=F(f(z),g(z)).$$

Proof: Letting $f(z)=z$,  $g(z)=c$ shows that $z\mapsto F(z,c)$ is holomorphic. Similarly for $F(c,w)$, so a theorem of Hartogs shows that $F$ is a holomorphic function of two variables. Now $F(0,0)=0$, but the zeroes of  a holomorphic function in $\Bbb C^2$ cannot be isolated, by another theorem of Hartogs.  So it cannot happen that $F(f(z),g(z))=0$ if and only if $f(z)=g(z)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am actually asking for a weaker condition. I don't require $F$ to be holomorphic.

Comment: @JaeyoonKim ??? I didn't require $F$ to be holomorphic! If $F(f,g)$ is a holomorphic function with zero set the intersection of the two  zero sets, for eery $f$ and $g$, it _follows_ that $F$ is holomorphic - I gave a proof of that.